# Notifications through Task Scheduler in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, class, kernel, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to make my task appear on the notifications part. I have set the task scheduler already (Windows 10) and I have this function inside a class:

```
public static function forecastModal($store_id = NULL)
{

    $inventory_forecasts = DB::table('restock_inventories', $store_id)
        ->join('product', function($join){
            $join->on('restock_inventories.product_id', '=', 'product.id');
        })
        ->where('product.store_id', $store_id)
        ->where('product.sku_type', '!=', 'Old Inactive')
        ->where('restock_inventories.days_of_supply', '<', 14)
        // ->distinct()
        ->select('product.sku', 'restock_inventories.days_of_supply')
        ->groupBy('product.sku')
        ->paginate(10);

        $data = [
            'restock_inventories' => $inventory_forecasts
        ];

        Log::info("Matt");

        return response()->json($inventory_forecasts);

        event(new TaskSchedulesEvents('Days of Supply', 'Days of Supply', $store_id, Auth::id(), 'inventory-forecast-v2/'.$store_id));
}
```

I tried putting the event inside a controller function(for the navbar) and it was working. The notification "Days of Supply" appeared. But when I put it back inside the Class under the folder "Common" it's not working again.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `event(....` above `return response(`, return completes the method, anything after it will not execute.